# Color Google map road X meters from current location

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, polyline, directions

I hope this question fits here.
I want to color the map from the user current location and X meters to the right and left (via polyline or styled maps), but only if there's a real road. For example, if the user is in foo street number 10, I want to color this street from number 1 to 20, but I want to make sure those street numbers exists, and if not - to color till the end of the street. 
I know there's reverse geocoding, but it seems endless to check each and every number from each user. 
Is there more elegant way to do it?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520121/customize-color-scheme-of-google-maps-v2-in-android

Comment: @d.datul1990 Thanks, I'll check it out.